# SQL DATEDIFF Returns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I don't want to show my whole query as it is very specific but I will try to explain briefly.

The following query works perfectly and I got 6000 records as a result.

```
  SELECT
      DISTINCT ID,
      NAME,
      CASE WHEN A.ID IS NULL THEN 'NOT EX.'
       ELSE A.Whatever
      END AS A_Whatever,
      D.Z1 AS A.P 
      --AND SO ON......          

  FROM A 

      INNER JOIN A ON A.ID= B.ID AND A.Nb= B.Nb
      LEFT JOIN T AS T2_ID ON T2_D.Z= A.Z
      LEFT JOIN L1 ON A.NR = L1.NR AND A.S = L1.S
      LEFT JOIN LF ON LF.NR = L1.LNR
      --AND SO ON.......
```

However, when i add a DATEDIFF calculation I get only 100 Rows in the answer:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT 
      ID,
      NAME,
      CASE WHEN A.ID IS NULL THEN 'NOT EX.'
        ELSE A.Whatever
      END AS A_Whatever,
      D.Z1 AS A.P,
      DATEDIFF(dd,A.ADATE,A.BDATE)

FROM A 
  INNER JOIN A ON A.ID= B.ID AND A.Nb= B.Nb
  LEFT JOIN T AS T2_ID ON T2_D.Z= A.Z
  LEFT JOIN L1 ON A.NR = L1.NR AND A.S = L1.S
  LEFT JOIN LF ON LF.NR = L1.LNR
  --AND SO ON.......
```

I am expecting 6000 rows with a correct query using DATEDIFF in line with what the following query returns:

```
  SELECT 
      DISTINCT *,
      DATEDIFF(dd,A.ADATE,A.BDATE)
  FROM A 
      INNER JOIN A ON A.ID= B.ID AND A.Nb= B.Nb
      LEFT JOIN T AS T2_ID ON T2_D.Z= A.Z
      LEFT JOIN L1 ON A.NR = L1.NR AND A.S = L1.S
      LEFT JOIN LF ON LF.NR = L1.LNR
      --AND SO ON.......
```

But I do not need all of them I need just the selected ones and the DATEDIFF but combining the queries above did not work for some reason that i do not know.  Can anyone see why i am not getting the expected row count in my second query?

Comment: That's because `DISTINCT` in SQL Server applies to all the columns, so when you added the `DATEDIFF`, it returned the records with distinct values in that field too. You will have to use another technique than `DISTINCT`, but it is hard to give you the best solution without seeing your full query.

Comment: @RacilHilan Thnx for the answer but in the last query i do apply DISTINCT * and I get all the all the records the whole 6000 beside the DATEDIFF for them, I do not think applying DISTINCT will change the result if u taking all columns or just couple of them

Comment: Yes, it will change the result. It returns distinct rows, not distinct individual columns. So when you say `SELECT DISTINCT a, b` it returns distinct combination of `a` and `b`, not distinct values of `a` plus distinct values of `b`.

Comment: When you include datediff: **Are you also reducing the number of columns that get displayed?**  I suspect that the "cut down" queries you have provided has also cut out the detail we may need to really help you. *also* What your question really needs is a sample of your results `1.` before the datediff and `2.` after the datediff.

Answer (score 0):

You can just wrap your query in a `CTE` and perform the `DATEDIFF` on the result set returned by the `CTE`:

```
WITH DISTINCT_CTE AS (
   SELECT
         DISTINCT ID,
         NAME,
         CASE WHEN A.ID IS NULL THEN 'NOT EX.'
              ELSE A.Whatever
         END AS A_Whatever,
         D.Z1 AS A.P 
         --AND SO ON......              
   FROM A 

        INNER JOIN A ON A.ID= B.ID AND A.Nb= B.Nb
        LEFT JOIN T AS T2_ID ON T2_D.Z= A.Z
        LEFT JOIN L1 ON A.NR = L1.NR AND A.S = L1.S
        LEFT JOIN LF ON LF.NR = L1.LNR
           --AND SO ON.......
)
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(dd, ADATE, BDATE)
FROM DISTINCT_CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a subquery... first subquery the entire thing.

In the receiving query do another subquery for the DATEDIFF. For this subquery you need the primary key to get back to the correct row for the dates, which if I'm interpreting correctly is `A.ID`.

```
SELECT dT.ID, dT.Name, dT.A_Whatever           
      ,(SELECT DATEDIFF(dd, A2.ADATE, A2.BDATE)
          FROM A AS A2
         WHERE dT.ID = A2.ID --the primary key
       ) AS [DateDiff]
        --AND SO ON........
  FROM ( 
         SELECT DISTINCT ID,
                NAME,
                CASE WHEN A.ID IS NULL THEN 'NOT EX.'
                                       ELSE A.Whatever
                END AS A_Whatever,
                D.Z1 AS A.P 
               --AND SO ON......          

         FROM A 

             INNER JOIN A ON A.ID= B.ID AND A.Nb= B.Nb
             LEFT JOIN T AS T2_ID ON T2_D.Z= A.Z
             LEFT JOIN L1 ON A.NR = L1.NR AND A.S = L1.S
             LEFT JOIN LF ON LF.NR = L1.LNR
             --AND SO ON.......
      ) AS dT
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query :

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.DateDiff
FROM ( 
    SELECT DISTINCT ID,
            NAME,
            CASE WHEN A.ID IS NULL THEN 'NOT EX.'
                                   ELSE A.Whatever
            END AS A_Whatever,
            D.Z1 AS A.P 
           --AND SO ON......          
    FROM A 
         INNER JOIN B ON A.ID= B.ID AND A.Nb= B.Nb
         LEFT JOIN T AS T2_ID ON T2_D.Z= A.Z
         LEFT JOIN L1 ON A.NR = L1.NR AND A.S = L1.S
         LEFT JOIN LF ON LF.NR = L1.LNR
         --AND SO ON.......
  ) AS T1

JOIN (SELECT ID, DATEDIFF(dd, ADATE, BDATE) as DateDiff from A as A2) AS T2
ON T1.ID= T2.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

As the following attempts to display, if you are using `select distinct` AND removing date columns from view when introducing `datediff()` into the `select clause` that could be the cause of the change in rows returned. Note in query 1 that as long as `adate` or `bdate` are displayed 5 rows would be returned, but without them (query 2) you just get one row. Alternatively, if you removed distinct,from query 2 you would get all 5 rows but just the one column (this isn't shown below).

try it out at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/49ba3/2)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Sample
    ([ADATE] datetime, [BDATE] datetime)
;

INSERT INTO Sample
    ([ADATE], [BDATE])
VALUES
    ('2017-10-01 00:00:00', '2017-10-06 00:00:00'),
    ('2017-10-02 00:00:00', '2017-10-07 00:00:00'),
    ('2017-10-03 00:00:00', '2017-10-08 00:00:00'),
    ('2017-10-04 00:00:00', '2017-10-09 00:00:00'),
    ('2017-10-05 00:00:00', '2017-10-10 00:00:00')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select distinct 'q1' qry, adate, bdate, datediff(day,adate,bdate) days_diff
from sample
order by adate
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/49ba3/2/0)**:

```
| qry |                adate |                bdate | days_diff |
|-----|----------------------|----------------------|-----------|
|  q1 | 2017-10-01T00:00:00Z | 2017-10-06T00:00:00Z |         5 |
|  q1 | 2017-10-02T00:00:00Z | 2017-10-07T00:00:00Z |         5 |
|  q1 | 2017-10-03T00:00:00Z | 2017-10-08T00:00:00Z |         5 |
|  q1 | 2017-10-04T00:00:00Z | 2017-10-09T00:00:00Z |         5 |
|  q1 | 2017-10-05T00:00:00Z | 2017-10-10T00:00:00Z |         5 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select distinct 'q2' qry, datediff(day,adate,bdate) days_diff
from sample
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/49ba3/2/1)**:

```
| qry | days_diff |
|-----|-----------|
|  q2 |         5 |
```